# Teardown of Multiple Threaded Tests with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, nunit, selenium-webdriver-c#, threading

I'm trying to run multiple test cases with Nunit in C# in which every test needs its own Selenium Chrome Driver.

Before it was threaded, I handled the chrome driver with `[Setup]` and `[Teardown]` like so:

```
[TestFixture]
[SingleThreaded]
 public class MyThreadedTest
{
    private IWebDriver _driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _driver = new ChromeDriver();
        _driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Teardown()
    {
        _driver?.Quit();
    }
...
```

Now, however, I'm using `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.All)]` instead of `[SingleThreaded]`.

This means that all of my test cases that happen below that will all **attempt to use the *same* Chrome Driver**, instead of spawning a new one for each session.

A solution to this problem would be to do the setup and tear down in the actual test case, but then I don't get the nice tear down function that I've come to love with Nunit, because the driver will wind up being out of scope.

**So my question is this:** Is there a way to handle threaded setup and tear down in a more graceful way? I'm looking for some way to handle threaded setup and teardown; similar to what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131758/nunit-cleanup-after-test-failure) touches on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the [ThreadLocal Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1?view=netframework-4.8), so each running thread would be assigned it's own webdriver instance.

See pseudocode to get the idea:

```
private static readonly ThreadLocal<IWebDriver> WebDrivers = new ThreadLocal<IWebDriver>();

public static IWebDriver Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (WebDrivers.Value == null)
        {
            Log.Warn("Please call method 'Start' before can get Driver");
        }

        return WebDrivers.Value;
    }

    set => WebDrivers.Value = value;
}

public static void Start()
{
    WebDrivers.Value = new ChromeDriver();
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for, will experiment first, to see if I can use it in the Setup.

Comment: Works great! One thing of note is that I had to call Start() inside [Setup] and change every reference of my driver to WebDrivers.Value instead; but once I worked that out, it seems to do exactly what I wanted! Thanks!